# How to delete duplicate records from dataset based on max date in R?

Tags: r

```
Name    Date of Birth
Nitin   25-09-1991
Akash   25-09-1992
Nitin   25-09-1993
Nitin   25-09-1994
Nitin   25-09-1995
Nitin   25-09-1996
Rohit   25-09-1997
Akash   25-09-1998
Nitin   25-09-1999
Akash   25-09-2000
Rohit   25-09-2001
```

I want to find only unique name with max date.

Comment: What have you tried that did not work for you?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in a different number of ways, here is one using `aggregate`.

First coerce your dates to class `"Date"`.

```
dat $Date.of.Birth <- as.Date(dat$Date.of.Birth, "%d-%m-%Y")
```

Now `aggregate` the dates by `Name` and keep only the maxima.

```
aggregate(Date.of.Birth ~Name, dat, function(x) x[which.max(x)])
#   Name Date.of.Birth
#1 Akash    2000-09-25
#2 Nitin    1999-09-25
#3 Rohit    2001-09-25
```

**Data.**

```
dat <- read.table(text = "
Name    'Date of Birth'
Nitin   25-09-1991
Akash   25-09-1992
Nitin   25-09-1993
Nitin   25-09-1994
Nitin   25-09-1995
Nitin   25-09-1996
Rohit   25-09-1997
Akash   25-09-1998
Nitin   25-09-1999
Akash   25-09-2000
Rohit   25-09-2001
", header = TRUE)
```

Note that `read.table` replaces the spaces in the second column name by dots. You can force `read.table` to keep the column names as they are with argument `check.names = FALSE`.

Comment: What if Date is having time in HH:MM format (DD-MM-YYY HH:MM)

Comment: @Nitinzinjad Use `as.POSIXct(dat$Date.of.Birth, "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M")`. See `help("strptime")` for other date time formats.